# Unix Bash Shell Programming if directory exists

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

So I'm trying to get into an if statement in a bash shell script but I think I'm doing something wrong, anyways here's my sample code.

```
#!/bin/bash
read sd
if [ -d "~/tmp/$sd" ]; then
    echo "That directory exists"
else
    echo "That directory doesn't exists"
fi
;;
```

Am I pointing it to the correct directory? I want the user to input something which will be put into "sd" and if that subdirectory exists then it'll say it does, if not then it will go to the else and say it doesn't exist.

Comment: Tilde isn't expanded in quotes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try:

```
if [ -d ~/tmp/"$sd" ]; then
```

or:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/tmp/$sd" ]; then
```

Quoting prevents expansion of `~` into your home directory.

Comment: Thanks that worked! Now lets say there's a remote directory, how would I find the exact directory of that remote folder?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your code doesn't _find_ anything, it gets the directory name as input.

Comment: Right now the directory is pointing towards the /tmp on my personal computer correct? Lets say there was a remote computer I needed to connect to the to check if directories exists there, how would I go about finding the /tmp in the remote location? Pretty much how would I check if "-d" directory exists in a remote location?

Comment: Unless you've mounted the remote directory using NFS, SSHFS, FTPFS, or something like that, you can't access it using normal shell functions. You'd need to use a network client application like `ftp` or `curl`.

Comment: You can try something like this to check if directory exists on remote server:- `if [[ ssh user@example.com test -d /path/to/my/directory && echo exists ]] ; then
    # put code in here
fi`

Comment: @user2318083:- And if your folder is mounted on remote filesystem then try this: `df -P -T /my/path/to/folder | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: @RahulTripathi I will try that, it seems to make sense with the ssh. I'll report back in a bit when I try it out.

Comment: @RahulTripathi tried that first one with ssh, it says too many arguments. The second one looks a bit like things we didn't go over yet so I'm not sure what that is. I'll mess around with it a bit more.

Comment: Could you take this discussion to chat? It doesn't have anything to do with my answer, and I keep getting notified about all your comments.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:-

```
#!/bin/bash
read sd
if [ -d ~/tmp/"$sd" ]; then
    echo "That directory exists"
else
    echo "That directory doesn't exists"
fi
```

Comment: why are you using ;; at the end ?

Comment: @AhmedMasud:- Updated that. Just copied from the OP's question!!

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly it. Makes sense now

Comment: @AhmedMasud I used ;; at the end because that's what was shown to use for switch cases? Is that correct? I'm just going by what I was told. I didn't use my whole code.