# [-d: command not found

Tags: bash, shell

As per this answer: [Unix Bash Shell Programming if directory exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075074/unix-bash-shell-programming-if-directory-exists), I'm trying to check if a directory exists. However, when I run this, I get `line 1: [-d: command not found`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
if [-d "~/.ssl"]; then
  echo '~/.ssl directory already exists'
else
  sudo mkdir ~/.ssl/
fi
```

Comment: By the way, `[ -d "~/.ssl" ]` is looking for a directory name with a literal `~` character in it. You want `"$HOME/.ssl"`, or `[ -d ~/.ssl ]` without the quotes.

Comment: By the way, you don't really need the check. Just use `mkdir -p`. … er, wait, why are you only trying to create a directory if it already exists? Something fishy here...

Comment: @kojiro Oops, yeah I just realized I messed that up.

Comment: As another aside -- you shouldn't be using sudo for that mkdir. Having `~/.ssh` owned by a different user than your `$HOME` (which is exactly what you get when you do that `sudo` -- a `~/.ssh` owned by `root`) is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
[-d
```

is not a command.

```
[ -d
```

is the [`test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) command with the -d option.

Space matters.

(Also, the `[` command needs to end with a `]` parameter, which likewise has to be separated from other arguments by whitespace.)

That's the crux of the matter. There is another issue, though: If you quote the tilde, it doesn't expand. (This is one of the rare place where you may want to avoid quotes.) Quotes are great, though, so why not write `"$HOME/.ssl"`? (There's a subtle difference between ~ and "$HOME", but it doesn't matter for most uses.)

Honestly, all you really need is probably:

```
if mkdir -p ~/.ssl; then
  # Do stuff with new directory
else
  # Handle failure (but keep in mind `mkdir` will have its own error output)
fi
```

Comment: Who downvoted this? It's entirely correct.

Comment: Is point 2 still the same or was the question's code changed? It looks like currently, it is meant check to see if the directory exists and create it if it doesn't.

Comment: @heretoinfinity The original code did have the checks reversed. I'll make a note of it in an edit.